# How can I change the behaviour of selecting a draggable cell with VoiceOver in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, accessibility, voiceover

I'm very new to `iOS` and accessibility but I am trying to write an `iOS` app for visually impaired people that will also be user-friendly for sighted people.

It involves the moving of cells from one `UICollectionView` to another. The second `UICollectionView` is like a big square grid of cells and I have implemented drag and drop for sighted people. However, for blind people, I need some other way to move the cells as my testers, who are blind, tell me it's unlikely for them to use a drag and drop app.

The problem is if I turn VoiceOver on, the double tap gesture does nothing. If I double tap and hold, it selects a cell to be dragged, rather than just selecting an item to be moved and waiting to be told where to move it.

Is there some way to have drag and drop for when VoiceOver is off plus a different approach to moving the same item if VoiceOver on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some information about Drag & Drop using VoiceOver in the `What's New in Accessibility` [WWDC 2017 video](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DragAndDrop) with a perfectly detailed summary.

`accessibilityDragSourceDescriptors` and `accessibilityDropPointDescriptors` seem to be the most important variables to be used.

I never implemented it myself but this site is the first place I would go to find the proper way to do it.

Comment: Thanks XLE, this will be my primary focus for making the app accessible for now as I'm not sure of another way and this is probably the recommended way to achieve accessibility here. Regarding having different approaches on the same object, do you know if that's also possible?

Comment: @peteypiper: in my view, that's the only way to reach your goal with VoiceOver: this feature is definitely made for this kind of use case.  ;o)